# I cant understand how the function subset(X,Y) works

Tags: prolog

Can somebody to explain me this code? I try for hours to understand but i can't understand this...

```
subset([],[]).
subset([X|L],[X|S]) :- subset(L,S).
subset(L, [_|S]) :- subset(L,S).
```

Comment: Did you try `trace.` with sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that you have a list `[1,4]`, then there are four possible solutions: `[1,4]`, `[1]`, `[4]`, and `[]`, so if you call `subset(L, [1,4])`, we get:

```
?- subset(L, [1,4]).
L = [1, 4] ;
L = [1] ;
L = [4] ;
L = [].
```

The Prolog predicate returns for an empty list an empty list, which is indeed the only sublist we can generate:

```
sublist([], []).
```

for a sublist with *at least* one element `X` there are each time two possibilities: include `X` in the result, or do not include `X` in the result. In both cases we *recurse* on the tail of the list. The tail thus contains the remaining elements, and for each of these elements, there is again a decision point whether to include these elements or not.

In pseudo-code, an evaluation tree could thus look like:

```
subset(L, [1,4]) :-
    subset([1|L], [1|S]) :-
        subset([4|L], [1|S]) :-
            subset([], []).  % outer L=[1,4]
        subset(L, [1|S]) :-
            subset([], []).  % outer L=[1]
    subset(L, [1|S]) :-
        subset([4|L], [1|S]) :-
            subset([], []).  % outer L=[4]
        subset(L, [1|S]) :-
            subset([], []).  % outer L=[]
```

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to make this not recognize the empty list as a subset? I know the empty list is subset of all lists but i want to know if there is one way

Comment: @Giannis: yes, although that requires some extra logic. Perhaps it is better to ask a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

We can re-write it (nearly) equivalently to push the unifications out of the rules' headers, to make the code's structure more visually apparent:

```ml
subset(A,B) :- B=[], A=[].

subset(A,B) :- B=[X |    S], 
               A=[X | L], 
               subset(L, S).

subset(A,B) :- B=[_ |    S], 
               A=     L, 
               subset(L, S).
```

So `A` is a subset of `B`, if

- `B=[]` **and** `A=[]`, ***or***
- `A` contains the first element of `B`, etc. ***or***
- `A` does *not* contain the first element of `B`, etc.

That is all.